# Rational Equations why aren't both conditions true

Tags: linear-algebra, rational-functions

If this is true : $(x - 1) - x = x - (x+1)$ Why isn't $$\frac{2}{x-1}-\frac{2}{x}=\frac{2}{x}-\frac{2}{x+1}$$ also true?

- Flew in a plane in still air to a place $900$ km away. On the return flight, a tailwind increased the speed by $45$ km/h. The return trip was $1.5$ h less than the flight to the camp. Determine the speed of the plane on the return.

I did $\frac{900}{x}-\frac{900}{x+45}=\frac{3}{2}$ but the solution says the correct to be $\frac{900}{x-45}-\frac{900}{x}=\frac{3}{2}$. I don't understand what difference it makes which speed we make the variable $x$.

Comment: Because $\frac{1}{a+b}\neq\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}$ in general.

Comment: Why should it be true?  Division is not the same as subtraction.  That's like saying "a cat has four legs" is true, why isn't "a person has four legs" true?

Comment: Plus, if $x\in\{-1,0,1\}$, then $(x-1)-x=x-(x+1)$ is true but one of the fractions $\frac{1}{x-1}$, $\frac{1}{x}$ or $\frac{1}{x+1}$ won't even make sense...

Comment: The numerators are equal.  The denominators are not.

Comment: Because the reciprocal function is not a homomorphism from the *additive* group $\mathbf R$ into itself.

Comment: @Bernard I'm sure someone who hasn't noticed that $\frac{1}{a+b}=\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}$ isn't true will understand your comment.

Comment: @NeedForHelp: I know. It was just for fun. I'm from a generation which learnt some basic notions of group theory in high school.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For the first question:**

We have:
$$(x-1)-x=x-(x+1)$$
This is therefore true (power of $-1$ on both sides):
$$\frac{1}{(x-1)-x}=\frac{1}{x-(x+1)}$$
Hence, this is also true (multiplying both sides by $2$):
$$\frac{2}{(x-1)-x}=\frac{2}{x-(x+1)}$$
However, you cannot seperate the denominator as follows:
$$\frac{2}{(x-1)-x}\neq \frac{2}{x-1}-\frac{2}{x}$$
You can verify that this does not work with a counter-example. For example, try $x=6$:
$$\frac{2}{(6-1)-6}\neq \frac{2}{6-1}-\frac{2}{6}$$
$$-2 \neq \frac{1}{15}$$
Or, you can try it with $x=0$, and realise that $\frac{2}{0}$ is undefined.

**For the second question:** It does not matter whichever speed you define as $x$. For example, I deduce that from the answer you were given that they've denoted $x$ as the speed with the tailwind (return trip). You've denoted $x$ as the speed without the tailwind (on the forward trip). Therefore, when you solve for $x$ with your equation, you will get the speed without the tailwind. From that value, you can solve for the other speed (with tailwind).

Comment: In a word problem such as - flew in a plane in still air to a place 900 km away. On the return flight, a tailwind increased the speed by 45 km/h. The return trip was 1.5 h less than the flight to the camp. Determine the speed of the plane on the return. How would we know which variable to make x since 900/x - 900/x+45 = 3/2 would be different of 900/x-45 - 900/x = 3/2

Comment: @padapa I'll add this to my answer too.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter whether $x$ stands for the starting speed, or the returning speed of the plane. Pick one, be clear about what $x$ means, and use it consistently in your work.

You are defining $x$ to be the *starting* speed of the plane. When you solve your equation, the return speed will be $x+45$, which you will report as your answer to the problem.

If you use the approach outlined in the solution, then $x$ is defined as the *returning* speed of the plane, and you will report $x$ as the answer to the problem.

The answer should be the same under both approaches. *Both approaches are correct*. But this doesn't mean you can equate the two expressions $\frac{900}{x}-\frac{900}{x+45}$ and $\frac{900}{x-45}-\frac{900}{x}$, since $x$ has a *different* meaning in the two approaches.